# R Replace column values in dataframe base on matching indexing column in separate dataframe

Tags: r, merge, left-join, mutate

I have a dataframe 'df1' that looks like:

| Number | Variable1 | Variable | Variable3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C |
| 2 | A | B | C |
| 3 | A | B | C |
| 4 | A | B | C |
| 5 | A | B | C |

And I have a second dataframe 'df2' that looks like:

| Number | Variable1 | Variable | Variable3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D | E | F |
| 2 | G | H | I |
| 3 | J | K | L |
| 4 | M | N | O |
| 15 | P | Q | R |

I want to update the three Variable columns in df1 with the data in the Variable columns in df2 based on matching values in Number so that df1 ends up looking like:

| Number | Variable1 | Variable | Variable3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D | E | F |
| 2 | G | H | I |
| 3 | J | K | L |
| 4 | M | N | O |
| 5 | A | B | C |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `power_left_join` from [`powerjoin`](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/powerjoin) package with `conflict = coalesce_yx` like this:

```r
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "Number", conflict = coalesce_yx)
#>   Number Variable1 Variable Variable3
#> 1      1         D        E         F
#> 2      2         G        H         I
#> 3      3         J        K         L
#> 4      4         M        N         O
#> 5      5         A        B         C
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 'Number    Variable1   Variable    Variable3
1   A   B   C
2   A   B   C
3   A   B   C
4   A   B   C
5   A   B   C
', header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = 'Number    Variable1   Variable    Variable3
1   D   E   F
2   G   H   I
3   J   K   L
4   M   N   O
15  P   Q   R
', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: This solution works great, although maybe not as straightforward as the dplyr solution. You were first, so I'll mark this as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Would be helpful if dput(df) done. Have created another dataset for replication

```
df1<-cbind.data.frame(id=c(1:5),var1=rep("A",5),var2=rep("B",5),var3=rep("C",5))

df2<-cbind.data.frame(id=c(1:4,15),var1=LETTERS[7:11],var2=LETTERS[12:16],var3=LETTERS[16:20])


df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(var1 = coalesce(var1.y, var1.x),
         var2 = coalesce(var2.y, var2.x),
         var3 = coalesce(var3.y, var3.x)) %>%
  select(-var1.y, -var1.x,
         -var2.y, -var2.x,
         -var3.y, -var3.x)
```

Comment: This solution probably works, but there are different column names than the question, so not quite what was asked. Thank you for your efforts though.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, we can use `rows_update`

```
library(dplyr)
rows_update(df1, df2, by = 'Number', unmatched = "ignore")
```

-output

```
  Number Variable1 Variable Variable3
1      1         D        E         F
2      2         G        H         I
3      3         J        K         L
4      4         M        N         O
5      5         A        B         C
```

Comment: Also a great solution and very simple. In my mind, I was thinking there had to be a dplyr solution, but I kept trying the wrong functions. Thank you for introducing me to rows_update.

Answer (score 0):

You could update df1 while joining using data.table package and `fcoalesce` function:

```
library(data.table)

cols = c("Variable1", "Variable", "Variable3")

setDT(df1)[df2, (cols) := Map(fcoalesce, mget(paste0("i.", cols)), mget(cols)), on="Number"]
    

   Number Variable1 Variable Variable3
    <int>    <char>   <char>    <char>
1:      1         D        E         F
2:      2         G        H         I
3:      3         J        K         L
4:      4         M        N         O
5:      5         A        B         C
```